# Objective-C changing UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I make a quiz game.I put a label for question in the screen.When I was trying to change it's text the text didn't change.

QuizScreen.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
int score = 0;
int lives = 3;
int QuestionSelected = 0;
NSString *AnswerRunning;
@interface QuizScreen : UIViewController
{

    IBOutlet UITextField *Answer;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Go;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Question;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Session;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Lives;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Score;
    IBOutlet UIButton *Exit;

}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
-(IBAction)GoBtn:(id)sender;
-(void)questioning;

@end
```

QuizScreen.m

```
#import "QuizScreen.h"

@interface QuizScreen ()

@end

@implementation QuizScreen
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
-(IBAction)GoBtn:(id)sender{

    switch (QuestionSelected) {
        case 0:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            QuestionSelected = QuestionSelected + 1;
            break;
        case 7:
            if ([Answer.text isEqualToString: @"YOUR WORD"]){
                score = score + 1;
                Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i" , score];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct Answer!! Score +1"];
            }else{
                lives = lives - 1;
                Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lives: %i" , lives];
                Session.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong Answer!!! Lives -1"];
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
-(void)questioning {
    switch (QuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
        Question.text = @"You can only keep it once you give it to somebody.What is it?";

        break;
    case 1:
        Question.text = @"Light hides me and darkness kills me.What am I?";

        break;
    case 2:
        Question.text = @"Voiceless it cries,Wingless flutters,Toothless bites,Mouthless mutters.";

        break;
    case 3:
        Question.text = @"What goes in the water black and comes out red?";

        break;
    case 4:
        Question.text = @"It's hard to give up.Remove part of it and you still have a bit.Remove another part, but bit is still there.Remove another and it remains.What is it?";
               break;
    case 5:
        Question.text = @"With pointed fangs I sit and wait,with piercing force I serve out fate.Grabbing bloodless victims, proclaiming my might;physically joining with a single bite.What am I?";

        break;
    case 6:
        Question.text = @"Jasmine has a toaster with two slots that toasts one side of each piece of bread at a time, and it takes one minute to do so.If she wants to make 3 pieces of toast, what is the least amount of time she needs to toast them on both sides?";

        break;
    case 7:
        Question.text = @"A man was born on January 1st, 23 B.C. and died January 2nd, 23 A.D. How old did he live to be?";

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

When I run it and write the answer the label's text doesn't change.I tried stringWithFormat but it doesn't work.The strange part is the session label's text changes.But I couldn't find any differences

Comment: Did you debug and check that everything is set properly? Does the label only ever have the default text?

Comment: what is print in the label

Comment: all label are not work or any one of

Comment: Implement NSLog for checking value stored in label.

Comment: what is question selected and where you get that in runtime

Comment: check your iboutlet connection it properly connected or not

Comment: My IBOutlet is connected properly.

Comment: I debugged and everything is OK. My label's default text is the first question @Wain

Comment: @iDev just the question label doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Question label's text changes only in method:
-(void)questioning;

But I can't find where you are calling one. Set breakpoint on entrance of it, mb you are never getting there. As I understood your code [self questioning] should be called in viewDidLoad and at the end of GoBtn: methods.

P.S. 
You should pay attention to the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html), [General Coding Standards](http://www.education.vic.gov.au/devreskit/appdev/standards/general/general-standards-summary.htm) and [Conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW1). Especially to the naming variables, data types, methods e.t.c. (E.g. variables shouldn't start with capital letter, Class or structures should)

Comment: I'm new to Objective-C iOS SDK(I just watched one video on youtube.).I'll pay attention to it.